# Necessity - Reasons of a passage in a proof of Hatcher vol. 2

Tags: proof-verification, vector-bundles, topological-k-theory

Some words about the context of the proposition. Hatcher is defining [operations on vector bundles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle#Operations_on_vector_bundles) over the same base space $B$. We are speaking about the Whitney sum here, and it is proving that if $B$ is compact Hausdorff then exists the inverse under Whitney sum of a given vector bundles.

[image: hatcher vol. 2]

[Hatcher vol. 2 Vector Bundles & K-theory pag. 13]

**My question is:** I don't see the necessity of using [Urysohn's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma) (U-L) in this proof. Am I wrong?

**for what I've understood**, Hatcher uses U-L to have an open cover of $B$, but by definition exists already a cover (the same Hatcher consider!) of $B$ with the trivialization property (and I can assume it is open). Moreover I can't appreciate the need of define $g_i : E \to \mathbb{R}^n$ by $g_i(v)=\varphi_i(p(v))[\pi_i(h_i(v))]$ instead of $g_i(v)=\pi_i(h_i(v))$ for $v \in U_x$ or $0$ elsewhere. The properties required holds thanks to $h_i$ **not** thanks to the continuous function $\varphi_i$. So why passing through U-L?

Maybe I can't appreciate some delicate passage in this proof. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hatcher uses the $\varphi_i$ so that he can obtain a maps $g_i:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, instead of just having maps $p^{-1}(U_i)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: so the problem in my definition of the $g_i$'s would be proving continuity?

Comment: @RicPed To get a map $E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$, you need the domain of each $g_i$ to be $E$.  The domains of your $g_i$'s are just $p^{-1}(U_i)$.  So, the problem would be that you would not be able to construct a map on all of $E$.

Comment: @Johnson I define $g_i$ to be zero elsewhere, so in fact it is defined all over $E$. So according to me the problem is continuity

Comment: @RicPed Sorry, didn't see the "$0$ elsewhere" part.  Yes, continuity is the issue.

Comment: perfect, thanks (accepted obviously)